# Opening Apple Calendar from my apps

Tags: iphone, calendar

is there a way to know the URL identifier / URL schemes of Apple Calendar?
I would like to launch it from app.
Thanks ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There does not appear to be a published Custom URL scheme but you can access the Calendar information through the

`EKEventStore` and `EKEvent` APIs

There is also the `EKEventEditViewController` to assist with presenting the UI

Comment: thanks alot ^-^ Have to look through the APIs and see what I can do